# There i a problem executing code in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I am learning Python. Now whenever I try to run a code it does not get implemented. It shows In [*] instead of In [1] whenever I run the cell. Is there any solution for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cell is still running. You can press the square button at the top to exit the process if you want.

I am assuming that it is because the code takes too long to run. I would recommend you to run something simple like

```
print("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your jupter notebook  is having problem  or  the code is running  is taking more time to execute or even  if you are using any loop the program  may bi in infinit loop